# Ubuntu system showing 100% CPU usage with no identifiable processes consuming CPU resources

Tags: cpu, kubernetes

I'm experiencing an issue on my Ubuntu system where the CPU usage consistently shows 100% utilization in system monitoring tools like top or htop. However, when I inspect the running processes, I can't seem to identify any particular process consuming a significant amount of CPU resources.

I've tried using commands like top, htop, and ps to list the running processes, but none of them indicate any process responsible for the high CPU usage. Additionally, I've checked for any background tasks or services, but haven't found anything unusual.

Could anyone suggest possible reasons for this behavior and how I might identify the cause of the high CPU usage in this scenario?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Results of top:

[image: top]

Results of htop:

[image: htop]

Results of iotop:

[image: iotop]

```
top - 11:44:24 up  7:42,  2 users,  load average: 64.00, 64.00, 64.00
Tasks: 655 total,   1 running, 654 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 99.9 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  64294.3 total,  58049.2 free,   4826.7 used,   1418.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  58782.7 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   2471 root      20   0 6083740  99296  65304 S   1.0   0.2   4:00.85 kubelet
    959 root      19  -1  135856  68372  67180 S   0.3   0.1   0:08.48 systemd-journal
   1534 root      20   0  760560  40344  30188 S   0.3   0.1   1:11.12 kube-proxy
   5509 root      20   0    9896   4556   3224 R   0.3   0.0   0:09.18 top
      1 root      20   0  169868  13532   8500 S   0.0   0.0   0:06.53 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:02.63 rcu_sched
     11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 migration/0
     12 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:1-rcu_par_gp
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.39 migration/1
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.39 migration/2
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.39 migration/3
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3
     32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd
     33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4
     34 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/4
     35 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.39 migration/4
     36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/4
     37 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0-mm_percpu_wq
     38 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0H-events_highpri
```

```
  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    17 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   33 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    49 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  2  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    18 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   34 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    50 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  3  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    19 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   35 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    51 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  4  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    20 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   36 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    52 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  5  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    21 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   37 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    53 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  6  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    22 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   38 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    54 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  7  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    23 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   39 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    55 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  8  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    24 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   40 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    56 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  9  [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    25 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   41 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    57 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  10 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    26 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   42 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    58 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  11 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    27 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   43 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    59 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  12 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    28 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   44 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    60 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  13 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    29 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   45 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    61 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  14 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    30 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   46 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    62 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  15 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    31 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   47 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    63 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  16 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    32 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]   48 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]    64 [||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]
  Mem[|||||||||                                                 4.72G/62.8G]   Tasks: 48, 609 kthr; 1 running
  Swp[                                                                0K/0K]   Load average: 64.03 64.01 64.00
                                                                               Uptime: 07:43:48

    PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
   5618 root       20   0  8640  4576  3332 R  2.0  0.0  0:00.10 htop
   2471 root       20   0 5941M 97764 65304 S  0.7  0.1  4:01.61 /usr/bin/kubelet --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///r
   5509 root       20   0  9896  4556  3224 S  0.7  0.0  0:09.49 top
     90 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.06 ksoftirqd/13
   1582 root       20   0 5942M 86312 54484 S  0.0  0.1  2:50.38 /usr/bin/containerd-bin/containerd
   1534 root       20   0  742M 40344 30188 S  0.0  0.1  1:11.38 /usr/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/kube-proxy-config.yaml
      1 root       20   0  165M 13532  8500 S  0.0  0.0  0:06.53 /sbin/init maybe-ubiquity
      2 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 kthreadd
      3 root        0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root        0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root        0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      8 root        0 -20     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
      9 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
     10 root       20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:02.64 rcu_sched
     11 root       RT   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.09 migration/0
     12 root      -51   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 idle_inject/0
     13 root       20   0     0     0     0 I  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 kworker/0:1-rcu_par_gp
     14 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 cpuhp/0
     15 root       20   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 cpuhp/1
     16 root      -51   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 idle_inject/1
     17 root       RT   0     0     0     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.39 migration/1
```

```
Total DISK READ:         0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:       111.91 K/s
Current DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE:     220.21 K/s
    TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
    871 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    7.22 K/s  0.00 %  3.50 % [jbd2/dm-1-8]
    959 be/3 root        0.00 B/s  101.08 K/s  0.00 %  0.03 % systemd-journald
   4378 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.01 % [kworker/u128:1-events_power_efficient]
   1598 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    3.61 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
      1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init maybe-ubiquity
      2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
      3 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
      4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_par_gp]
      6 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H-events_highpri]
      8 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
      9 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
     10 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
     11 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
     12 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/0]
     13 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:1-rcu_par_gp]
     14 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/0]
     15 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/1]
     16 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/1]
     17 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
     18 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
     20 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/1:0H-kblockd]
     21 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/2]
     22 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/2]
     23 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/2]
     24 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/2]
     26 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/2:0H-kblockd]
     27 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/3]
     28 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/3]
     29 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/3]
     30 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/3]
     32 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/3:0H-kblockd]
     33 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/4]
     34 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/4]
     35 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/4]
     36 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/4]
     37 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/4:0-mm_percpu_wq]
     38 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/4:0H-events_highpri]
     39 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/5]
     40 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [idle_inject/5]
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems likely that this is an issue related to Kubernetes. I would suggest adding that tag. What are your processor makes and models?

Comment: Thank you, on k8s, it's just a testing system and the model hasn't been loaded. I suspect the server has been hacked for running virtual currency, but I'm unable to handle it, except for reinstalling the system.

Comment: If you suspect hacking, maybe you should only run programs like ps, top, ...etc. from known clean media. try ls on /proc, and compare those processes to the output of ps to see which are "missing".

Comment: Long shot, are you running top/htop as root or as a regular user? By default, the PID directories under /proc are world-readable, but maybe someone/something changed those permissions.

Comment: What network card do you use? Do you have VF's enabled for the network card and  also what drivers version are you using for the network card?